# No. Of elements of order 2 in symmetricgroup of degree 5

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

How many elements of order 2 are there in symmetric group $S_5$?

Comment: Every $\sigma\in S_5$ can be written as product of disjoint cycles. Wonder wich products will have order $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : how many transpositions have you in $S_5$?

how many double transpositions have you in $S_5$?

Comment: There are 10 transpositions and 15 products of two disjoint transpositions. So, total 25 elements are in S_5.

Comment: Is it correct...?

Comment: @B.R.Datt, Yes it is.